How can I turn monthly based financial data into a regular table in excel
I have a table, on the left of the table there are about 10 columns of reference information, then as it goes to the right of that each month has about four columns of data.
I to transform it so all the data is in a single table so that I can do further analysis.
Starting with the below table

Generate this outcome

Id like to see either and excel formula or a power query / M query that can do this, I'm not looking for a macro.

Superuser is not a code (or formula) writing service. We're happy to help you improve code you've already begun writing yourself. Please share what you have tried so far to help us begin helping you.

Here is one way to accomplish the desired output using Power Query


To use Power Query follow the steps:

First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as Table1 and remember to uncheck My Table Has Headers



Next, open a blank query from Data Tab --> Get & Transform Data --> Get Data --> From Other Sources --> Blank Query



The above lets the Power Query window opens, now from Home Tab --> Advanced Editor --> And paste the following M-Code by removing whatever you see, and press Done


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    First2Rows = Table.FirstN(Source,2),
    Rows2Columns = Table.Transpose(First2Rows),
    FillDown = Table.FillDown(Rows2Columns,{"Column1"}),
    Merged = Table.CombineColumns(FillDown,{"Column1", "Column2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    Columns2Rows = Table.Transpose(Merged),
    Combined = Table.Combine({Columns2Rows,Table.RemoveFirstN(Source,2)}),
    PromotedHeaders = Table.PromoteHeaders(Combined, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    AddedIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(PromotedHeaders, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    UnpivotedOtherColumns = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(AddedIndex, {"Reference|ID", "Reference|NAME", "Reference|ROLE", "Index"}, "MONTH", "Value"),
    SplitColumnbyDelimiter = Table.SplitColumn(UnpivotedOtherColumns, "MONTH", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"MONTH.1", "MONTH.2"}),
    PivotedColumn = Table.Pivot(SplitColumnbyDelimiter, List.Distinct(SplitColumnbyDelimiter[MONTH.2]), "MONTH.2", "Value"),
    Sort = Table.Sort(PivotedColumn,{{"MONTH.1", Order.Ascending}, {"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    RemovedCol = Table.RemoveColumns(Sort,{"Index"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(RemovedCol,{{"Reference|ID", "ID"}, {"Reference|NAME", "NAME"}, {"Reference|ROLE", "ROLE"}, {"MONTH.1", "MONTH"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"



Lastly, to import it back to Excel --> Click on Close & Load or Close & Load To --> The first one which clicked shall create a New Sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.


